# Snapshot support in Teradata

Tags: backup, teradata

We want to know if Teradata supports snapshots/journalling. For example taking snapshot – point in time copy/image of one or multiple tables. Generally snapshots are used for taking backups without stopping regular batches. Today in our data-warehouse, we stop regular batches before taking backups. If anybody has used this feature of teradata please update here.

Answer (score 0):

You can define permanent BEFORE and/or AFTER journals for tables in Teradata.  Take a look at the DDL Syntax manual:

https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference%2FB035-1144-160K%2Fjbg1472241477989.html%23

I've never used the table journaling feature before, so can't give you any more specifics.

You can also make a backup of a table using the ARC utility -- I think it supports online backups.